# Rails rendering JSON in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am having trouble trying to render specific fields in my rails app my structure is like so:

### Home_controller.rb

```
  def index
    taobao_hash = OpenTaobao.get(
      :method => "taobao.tbk.item.get",
      :fields => "num_iid,title,nick,pict_url,cid,price,type,delist_time,post_fee,score,volume",
      :q => "snus",
      :page_size => 1,
      :sort => "_des",
    )

    h = JSON.parse(taobao_hash.to_json)
    render json: h["tbk_item_get_response"]
  end
```

How this renders my whole request as json like so

```
{
  "results": {
    "n_tbk_item": [
      {
        "nick": "恶毒对于",
        "num_iid": 17707525948,
        "pict_url": "http://img4.tbcdn.cn/tfscom/i2/TB1umhOHVXXXXa0aXXXXXXXXXXX_!!0-item_pic.jpg",
        "title": "瑞典戒烟产品唇烟嚼烟经典款General Classic White Portion Snus",
        "volume": 127
      }
    ]
  },
  "total_results": 99,
  "request_id": "1476rjvn5sc2g"
}
```

How would I go about only rendering `title` in my view? I can only seem to render everything.

Comment: How would i be able to do this for each result in the view?

Comment: `render json: h["tbk_item_get_response"]["results"]["n_tbk_item"].map{|x| x['title']}`

Comment: Say I want to add this into my view though is there any way i could call it from there so i could add my own html ect

Comment: If you're already calling `render json: {}`, you won't have access to your view anymore. If you're using a serializer/jbuilder however, you'd be able to manipulate the data. BTW, why do you have to do: `taobao_hash.to_json` again?

Comment: @oreoluwa What I'm trying to achieve is something like `@results.each do |result|` and then list out every title in my view. If i dont convert it to json rails throws errors on my side about it being a hash

Comment: Yeah, I guess what I mean is: if the result is already in `json`, you don't need to call `to_json` on it again. You can simply do: `JSON.parse(taobao_hash)`. If you're using something like jBuilder, you can easily update the result. Or usinf the approach suggested by @potashin, you can manipulate the title within the block as such: `render json: h["tbk_item_get_response"]["results"]["n_tbk_item"].map{|x| "<div>#{x['title']}</div>" }`